# Member in multiple hierarchies (forest?) into a single table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, metadata, pivot

if I have the following table:

```
Member_Key  Member_Name             col1    Mem1    col2    Mem2    col3    Mem3    col4    Mem4
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
31          100.00 - Some Account   9       Rollup1 268     Rollup2 246     Rollup3 238   Rollup4
31          100.00 - Some Account   270     Rollup5 271     Rollup6 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
31          100.00 - Some Account   283     Rollup7 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

The desired output is:

```
Member_Key    Member_Name    col1  mem1  col2  mem2  col3  mem3 col4 mem4 col5 mem5  col6  mem6  col7  mem7
```

I have been trying to get this done with 1 account so that I can try to make it dynamic for x number of accounts that have y number of rollups and put them into one variable-column result, but I can't seem to get this to work via using PIVOT or SELECT CASE. Any help or links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us more information. I am guessing the `member_key` and `member_name` are from a single table. Are the colx and memx columns from separate table that links to the first one? If the first table has col1, mem1, col2, mem2, ... , colc, memn then why would you need a pivot?

Comment: I used SSIS to split my hierarchy information into 2 tables: one that contains the actual hierarchy (parents and children) and then a list of the accounts themselves. The colx and memx columns come from the hierarchy table, where I used a materialized path function (via sqlserverbible.com ch.18) to get the path of the hierarchy. In this example, I used one account for simplicity. However, in the actual table, there are many accounts with varying levels in the hierarchy. So the final table isn't necessarily going to have 7 columns. I was trying to use pivot to make it dynamic.

Comment: Actually, it's ch.17... http://sqlserverbible.com/files/sqlserver2008bible_ch17.pdf. I take the materialized path (a string, i.e '2,54,220') and parse the numbers using a script component. The original example table above is the result of the script component output joined to the table with the list of accounts (to get the names and whatever other metadata necessary).

Answer (score 0):

I hope that below query is your answer:

```
SELECT *
From
    (SELECT  A.Member_Key,
            A.Member_Name,
            CASE B.n
                WHEN 1 THEN A.Mem1
                WHEN 2 THEN A.Mem2
                WHEN 3 THEN A.Mem3
                WHEN 4 THEN A.Mem4
            END AS Mem,
            CASE B.n
                WHEN 1 THEN A.Col1
                WHEN 2 THEN A.Col2
                WHEN 3 THEN A.Col3
                WHEN 4 THEN A.Col4
            END AS Col
        FROM MyTable A
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 
            UNION SELECT 2
            UNION SELECT 3
            UNION SELECT 4)B(n)
    )AS p
PIVOT (MIN(Col) FOR Mem IN ([Rollup1], [Rollup2], [Rullup3], [Rollup4], [Rollup5], [Rullup6], [Rullup7])) AS Pvt
```